# Owners in groovy closures

Tags: java, groovy, closures

According to "Groovy in Action", closures can be declared via several ways. A couple of ways:
def printer = { line -> println line }
def Closure getPrinter() {
    return { line -> println line }
}

According to [Closures, official documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) `owner` in closure

> "return the direct enclosing object, be it a closure or a class."

Ok, let's have a look at:

```
class Mother {
    def prop = 'prop'
    def method(){ 'method' }
    Closure birth (param) {
        def local = 'local'
        def closure1 = {
            [ this, prop, method(), local, param ]
        }
        return closure1
    }

    def birth2 = { param ->
        def local = 'local'
        def closure2 = {
            [ this, prop, method(), local, param ]
        }
        return closure2
    }
}
Mother julia = new Mother()
def closure = julia.birth('param')
assert closure.owner == julia
assert closure.delegate == julia

def closure2 = julia.birth2('param')
assert closure2.owner == julia  
assert closure2.delegate == julia
```

In both cases, `birth` anb `birth2` are closures according to documentation. Inside these closures we declare `closure1` and `closure2`. I gave them names just to refer to them. The owners of these `closure1` and `closure2` should refer to `birth` and `birth2`. According to the official documentation. But in first example `owner` refers to instance of class - `julia`. In the second example, I believe it refers to `birth2`, but don't know how to assert it.

Can anyone explain the difference, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`birth` is a method, not a closure

`birth2` is a closure

Therein lies the difference

Comment: it means that inside class when I declare: def Closure getPrinter() { return { line -> println line } } it is a method, not a closure. And explicite "Closure" means nothing in this case?

Comment: That's the return type. So it's a method that returns a closure.

Comment: Like `int add(int a, int b) { a + b }` is a method that accepts two ints and returns an int, `Closure method(String a) { { -> a * 2 } }` is a method that takes a string, and returns a Closure

Comment: `Closure clos = { String a -> { -> a * 2 } }` is a closure which accepts a string, and returns a closure

Answer (score 0):

You get already the explanation regarding the difference between `birth` and `birth2`, one is a method and the other is a closure. However, both return a `Closure` object and the question about how to assert the owner and the delegate is still not answered. Here it is:

```
class Mother {
    def prop = 'prop'
    def method(){ 'method' }
    Closure birth (param) {
        def local = 'local'
        def closure1 = {
            [ this, prop, method(), local, param ]
        }
        return closure1
    }

    def birth2 = { param ->
        def local = 'local'
        def closure2 = {
            [ this, prop, method(), local, param ]
        }
        return closure2
    }
}
Mother julia = new Mother()
def closure = julia.birth('param')
assert closure.owner == julia
assert closure.delegate == julia

def closure2 = julia.birth2('param')
assert closure2.owner ==  julia.birth2
assert closure2.delegate == julia.birth2
```

You are of course right, owner and delegate of `closure2` are `birth2`. The owner of the closure2 is the next object which holds it, which by definition is either an class or another closure. Note that the owner cannot be another method as we see in case of `closure1`.

The delegate of the closure is the context where that delegate solves it's names which by default is the owner. In our case the delegate of the `closure2` is `birth2`. The context of `birth2` where the names are solved is again it's owner by default which is the class `Mother`, that is why `prop` and `method()` are known in `closure2`.

However, groovy has a cool feature that allows you to change the context where a closure is evaluated, so you could call `closure2` for a completely unrelated object exposing the same names as `Mother`. This is possible by changing the delegate and either accessing the properties with delegate.property or by just changing the implicit delegation strategy.
See [delegate of a closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegate_of_a_closure).

Here is a small example how to use it:

```
class Person {
    String name
    int age
    def describe = { "$name is $age years old." }
}
person = new Person(name: 'John', age: 42)
assert person.describe() == "John is 42 years old."

closure = person.describe
closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
closure.delegate = [name: 'Mike', age:'66']
assert closure() == "Mike is 66 years old."
```